# is this possible in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to add 100 rows in a single insert, populating each field with the next in a series of numbers (and their string equivalents).

In other words, Something along these lines (myNumber would be a varchar, myOrder would be an int):

insert into myTable (myNumber, myOrder) select "0"-"99", select 1-100

I have a feeling this can't be done, but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to without creating a whole new table... Just as long as you have A table with as many records as you hope to add, even if there is no bearing on the content... You can do with MySQL query variables..

```
insert into YourTable ( YourSequence, YourStringVersion, field3 )
   ( SELECT 
           @seq:= @seq+1 YourSequence,
           CONVERT( @seq, CHAR(8) ) YourStringVersion,
           "Other Defaults" field3
        FROM 
           (select @seq := 1) vars,
            SomeTableWithAtLeast100Records limit 100 ) JustToAdd
```

Answer (score 0):

You **could** write the "select 0-99, select 1-100" as a set of unions:

```
select 0 as num, 1 as order
union all
select 1 as num, 2 as order
```

and then insert based on that result set.  Not a lot of fun though - best way to do this would probably be through a stored function and a cursor -- but that will be 1 row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't begin to imagine what problem you are trying to solve which needs that as its solution - you do seem to post a lot of enquiries with similarly odd questions.

Since you're looking for a code solution, you presumably want to do this lots of times. The short answer would be to use a procedure with a loop, or to maintain a table (could even be a subset of rows within 'myTable' then do

```
INSERT INTO myTable (mynumber, myorder, another) 
SELECT mynumber, myorder, 'new' 
FROM myTable WHERE another='TEMPLATE';
```

Comment: Peculiar accusation... which of my previous questions seem odd to you? As for my needs here, they are pretty straight forward. I have a table that represents a long list of sequential elements that are all virtually identical (imagine seats in a row, for instance) and I need to populate said table. Obviously this can be done with a script or a stored procedure, but I was curious if it can be done with straight SQL.